# Fixing double-ball joint on a 6'' scale action figure

Tags: adhesives, plastic

I currently have a Figma 6 inch scale figure and unfortunately, I broke off a peg from the double ball shoulder joint. The broken peg was stuck in the hole connecting the arm so I used a knife to jam it out. As a way of fixing the joint, I was hoping to use a screw and essentially screw it into the hole while using the head of the screw as a way to connect the arm to the double ball joint. I was thinking of applying a Loctite superglue at the head and fuse it to the area on the joint where the peg broke off.

Is this method of fixing my figure okay, so should I be causing more damage?

As an alternative method, I could just use the broken peg that I jammed out of the figure's arm and superglue it to the ball joint but I don't know if the peg will stay in place as the surface of the peg is uneven due to the jamming.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts! Could you post a picture of the broken joint? That would make it far easier to understand the size of the joint, how it should work in the end and maybe spark some good ideas.

Comment: It looks like you tried to post a picture but somehow posted only a comment about having posted a picture (which got edited out).  Give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

The latter idea of fixing the broken peg sounds the most practical. Strengthen the connection by inserting something strong, like part of a paper clip or a toothpick, to bridge the two pieces. If there is enough material there so that you can tap (drill) a small opening for the wire that is, just sticking something in without making room for it may split the plastic.

Also the choice of glue is important. There may be something stronger than super glue for the bond and some plastics may even take damage from it. Maybe the manufacturer sells or recommends one, or search on here for adhesive questions, there have been a few.